# Pandas DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I need to have a DateTimeIndex for my dataframe. Problem is my source file. The Date header is Date(dd-mm-yy), but the actual date data has the format dd:mm:yy (24:06:1970) etc. I have lots of source files so manually changing the header would be tedious and not good programing practice. How would one go about addressing this from within python?

Perhaps creating a copy of the source file opening it, searching for the date header, changing it and then closing it? I'm new to python so I'm not exactly sure if this is the best way to go about doing things and if it is, how do I implement such code?

Currently I have this;

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',
                    skiprows = 4,
                    parse_dates = {'stamp':[0,1]},
                    na_values = 'NaN',                    
                    index_col = 'stamp'
                 )
```

Where column 0 is the date column in question and column 1 is the time column.
I don't get any error messages just erroneous data.

Sorry, I should have added a snippet of the csv file in question.I've now provided it below;

```
some stuff I dont want 
some stuff I dont want 
some stuff I dont want 
some stuff I dont want 
Date(dd-mm-yy),Time(hh:mm:ss),Julian_Day
01:07:2013,05:40:41,182.236586,659,1638.400000
01:07:2013,05:44:03,182.238924,659,1638.400000
01:07:2013,05:47:48,182.241528,659,1638.400000
01:07:2013,05:52:21,182.244687,659,1638.400000
```

Comment: can you provide an example with csv data to read and the error message you get?

Comment: fyi, pandas doesn't care what the header of your source files says about the format of the dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is that the header line `Date(dd-mm-yy), Time(hh:mm:ss), Julian_Day` only appears to specify some of the column names. `Pandas` cannot infer what to do with the other data.

Try skipping the file's column name line and passing `pandas` a list of column `names` and defining your own `date_parser`:

```
def my_parser(date, time):
    import datetime
    DATE_FORMAT = '%d:%m:%Y'
    TIME_FORMAT = '%H:%M:%S'
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, DATE_FORMAT)
    time_weird_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, TIME_FORMAT)
    return datetime.datetime.combine(date, time_weird_date.time())

import pandas as pd
from cStringIO import StringIO

data = """\
some stuff I dont want 
some stuff I dont want 
some stuff I dont want 
some stuff I dont want 
Date(dd-mm-yy),Time(hh:mm:ss),Julian_Day
01:07:2013,05:40:41,182.236586,659,1638.400000
01:07:2013,05:44:03,182.238924,659,1638.400000
01:07:2013,05:47:48,182.241528,659,1638.400000
01:07:2013,05:52:21,182.244687,659,1638.400000
"""  

pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), skiprows=5, index_col=0, 
            parse_dates={'datetime':['date', 'time']}, 
            names=['date','time', 'Julian_Day', 'col_2', 'col_3'],
            date_parser=my_parser)
```

This should give you what you want.

As you said you are new to python, I should add that the  from `cStringIO import StringIO`, `data = """...`, and `StringIO(data)` parts are just so I could include the data directly in this answer in a runnable form.  You just need  `pd.read_csv(my_data_filename, ...` in your own code

Comment: Also pass in a `date_parser` to `read_csv` that can handle the weird date format.

Comment: Yup Thanks @U2EF1, I didn't spot that the date was falling through to today as a default. Fixed with a working parser now.

Comment: seems like there should be a better way of handling the time field than making it a `datetime` object with some weird default date. Having `datetime.time.strptime()` would be ideal but there is no such method. Importing the `time` module and casting also seems quite ugly and I don't jsut mean the module name collision with the 2nd argument of my_parser

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are really weird, you should just fix them all. If you really can't fix them on disk for some reason, I guess you can do it inline:

```
import re
from StringIO import StringIO
s = open('test.csv').read()
def rep(m):
    return '%s-%s-%sT' % (m.group('YY'), m.group('mm'), m.group('dd'))
s = re.sub(r'^(?P<dd>\d\d):(?P<mm>\d\d):(?P<YY>\d{4}),', rep, s, flags=re.M)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), skiprows=5, index_col=0, 
                 names=['time', 'Julian_Day', 'col_2', 'col_3'])
```

This just takes the weird dates like `01:07:2013,05:40:41` and formats them ISO style like `2013-07-01T05:40:41`. Then pandas can treat them normally. Bear in mind that these are going to be in UTC.